# execute Powershell in NSIS

Tags: xml, powershell, nsis, 32-bit, windows-task-scheduler

I encountered the following problem:
I'm trying to use a powershell script in NSIS but if I start the installer there pops up a powershell window but closes instantly.
All I can see is that powershell prints an error (some red letters), but I can't see what the error says due to it closing instantly.

All my script does is replacing Placeholder in a template .xml file, by replacing
"CURRENTPC\CURRENTUSERNAME" with the output of the command 'whoami' and in the end I import this XML file per 'schtask' into the Task Scheduler.

If I run my script separately it works as desired, but if I use the compiled setup the problem I described occurs.

Of course i spend time searching for a solution.
I tried the following:

- I build in a check in my script to see if it runs in 32-bit. If yes, restart in 64-bit
- I made a hardcoded 'cd' to the path where my .xml-template remains
- I executed the powershell inside NSIS via 'ExecWait', 'ns::ExecToLog' and 'ns::ExecToStack'

I don't know what to do anymore. I hope somebody can help.

For those who want to read the code:
This is how I use the script inside NSIS:

```
File ProcessControlTemplateFill.ps1

ExecWait 'powershell -inputformat none -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File ".\ProcessControlTemplateFill.ps1"'
```

And this is my .ps1-script:

```
    #############################################################################
#If Powershell is running the 32-bit version on a 64-bit machine, we 
#need to force powershell to run in 64-bit mode .
#############################################################################
if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq "AMD64") {
    write-warning "Y'arg Matey, we're off to 64-bit land....."
    if ($myInvocation.Line) {
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile $myInvocation.Line
    }else{
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
    }
exit $lastexitcode
}


write-host "Main script body"

#############################################################################
#End
############################################################################# 

cd C:\R15

$WERBINICH = whoami

ForEach($Datei in ls './sources/ProcessControlTemplate.xml') {

    $Zeilen =  Get-Content -Path $Datei.Fullname

    $ZeilenZähler = 1
    foreach($Zeile in $Zeilen)
    {

        $Zeile = $Zeile -replace 'CURRENTPC\\CURRENTUSERNAME', "$WERBINICH"

        Write-Host $Zeile

        If($ZeilenZähler -eq 1 ) {
           Out-File -FilePath $Datei.Fullname -InputObject $Zeile -Force
        }
        Else {
            Out-File -FilePath $Datei.Fullname -InputObject $Zeile -Force -Append
        }

        $ZeilenZähler++
    }
}
schtasks /create /f /XML .\sources\ProcessControlTemplate.xml /tn ProcessControl
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the NSIS installer? Why not just run the PowerShell script directly?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart 
The installer is Part of a Major project and the future "clients" that use my setup shouldn't have to use the setup and start the script afterwards manually

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have a big program, that I want want to bring on other PC's. The installer installs this program of mine, but the program has to be started at userlogin, therefore the scheduled task. The scheduled task has to be started in a certain directory. so a normal executed schtask within the NSIS installer won't work... So I thought I could use a script to modify the info into what I need and import them via xml... I hope this explains it in a better way

Comment: What is the error message? ExecToLog should show you.

Comment: @Anders Even if I use ExecToLog the powershell window closes instantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full path to ProcessControlTemplateFill.ps1, not a relative path. Use `Start-Sleep -s 10` in your powershell script to pause a bit so you can read the error.

Comment: It works just fine with full paths, I just tested. Remember that SetOutPath in NSIS changes the current directory but it should not matter because you should use full paths everywhere!